# sed paragraph tags

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

How can I wrap paragraphs in plain text with paragraph tags `{p}` before and `{/p}` after each paragraph using `sed`? Each paragraph is separated by blank lines. I can use `sed -e 's/^\s*$/<r>/ somefile.txt` to find every blank line in the text file, but this will always insert {p} everywhere and I don't quite understand, how to vary them. Also, there's no empty line after the very last paragraph, so it won't do anything for the last one.

Input text:

```
Section 5. General Information About Project Gutenberg-tm electronic
works.

Description

Professor Michael S. Hart is the originator of the Project Gutenberg-tm
concept of a library of electronic works that could be freely shared
with anyone.

Project Gutenberg-tm eBooks are often created from several printed
editions, all of which are confirmed as Public Domain in the U.S. unless
a copyright notice is included.
```

Required Output:

```
Section 5. General Information About Project Gutenberg-tm electronic
works.
{p}
Description
{/p}
{p}
Professor Michael S. Hart is the originator of the Project Gutenberg-tm
concept of a library of electronic works that could be freely shared
with anyone.
{/p}
{p}
Project Gutenberg-tm eBooks are often created from several printed
editions, all of which are confirmed as Public Domain in the U.S. unless
a copyright notice is included.
{/p}
```

Comment: show the input text

Comment: added to the question, cheers

Comment: good, you'll get a quick help if you also add the expected result (how it should look)

Comment: but the line `Section 5. General Information About Project Gutenberg-tm electronic works.` is also a paragraph, why it's not wrapped in your output?

Comment: because it's the title of text

Comment: ok, is it mandatory that each paragraph should be wrapped including empty lines before and after OR could we just wrap a paragraph text like `{p}Description{/p}` ?

Comment: I can suggest the following output: https://ibb.co/i2VZVk

Comment: It's mandatory that the empty lines before and after the paragraphs are changed to {p} and {/p}. So these tags will go before and after the paragraphs on separate lanes, no empty lines will be left at all.

Comment: have you seen the output from my link? is it suits you?

Comment: Almost, but not exactly, these signs shouldn't be on the same line as the paragraph, they should go before and after them and no empty lines should be left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you originally requested an `sed` solution, I append one:

```
sed '/./{H;1h;$! d}
g;/{p}$/d
s#^{p}.*#&\n{/p}#;p
s/.*/{p}/;h;d' somefile.txt
```

Explanation

- line 1: Append non-empty lines to the hold buffer (1st line copied instead of appended to avoid starting with newline). Continue for empty lines or end of file.
- line 2: Ignore buffers without text to handle multiple empty lines or empty lines at the end of the buffer
- line 3: If there is an opening tag, add a closing tag. Then print.
- line 4: Fill the hold buffer with a new opening tag.

Comment: Thanks, it works in an interactive mode, but what if I need to give an input of a file as a parameter? Looks a bit confusing...

Comment: Just add the filename after the script. Edited the answer to show. And yes, `sed` scripts are sometimes hard to read. I hope my explanation helps you understand

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'NR>1 && NF{$0="{p}" RS $0 RS "{/p}"}1' file
```

The output:

```
Section 5. General Information About Project Gutenberg-tm electronic works.

{p}
Description
{/p}

{p}
Professor Michael S. Hart is the originator of the Project Gutenberg-tm concept of a library of electronic works that could be freely shared with anyone. For thirty years, he produced and distributed Project Gutenberg-tm eBooks with only a loose network of volunteer support.
{/p}

{p}
Project Gutenberg-tm eBooks are often created from several printed editions, all of which are confirmed as Public Domain in the U.S. unless a copyright notice is included. Thus, we do not necessarily keep eBooks in compliance with any particular paper edition.
{/p}
```

---

`RS` - awk's record separator, defaults to the newline `\n`

`NR>1` - skips the first *header* line

`NF` - points to total number of fields of the line (considering non-empty lines)

Comment: `\n` is the default record separator. Use `RS=""` for the paragraph mode. `gawk -v RS= '{printf "%s", "{p}\n" $0 "\n{/p}" RT}'`

Comment: `$0 ~ /\S/` (same as `/\S/` alone) is GNU-specific. You can use `NF` (number of fields non-zero)  or `/[^[:space:]]/` portably

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, you're right. I've forgotten those moments. Thanks for the hints